# USing Entity Framework in NServiceBus endpoint throws EntityException "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, autofac, nservicebus5

I have an NServiceBus 5.2.9 endpoint and I am injecting a DBContext instance through NServiceBus.

Configuration:

```
public class ConfigureDependencyInjection : INeedInitialization
{
    public void Customize( BusConfiguration configuration )
    {
        configuration.RegisterComponents( reg =>
        {
            reg.ConfigureComponent<MyContext>( DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork );
        } );
    }
}
```

**This is the service's constructor:**

```
    public NotificationService( IBus bus, IMyContext context )
    {
        this.bus = bus;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

When I try to access the context field, I get the EntityException:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' in     NServiceBus.Core.dll
>   Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

**Why is this happening?**

I am unsure what the **correct lifetime scope** is for this. Is it `DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork`? DBContext is a UOW construct, but I am not sure if it's the same for NServiceBus.

**The message that comes in to this endpoint is always ONE (transport) message, so this should correctly apply to using a InstancePerUnitOfWork scope.**

The context instance is shared in the class, so every time I access it I lock against a syncLock like so:

```
lock ( syncLock )
{
    log.Info( "Get customers..." );

    var result = from c in context.Customers
    ...
    select...;
}
```

**How would I correctly use the DBContext, while keeping in thread-safety mind?**

Thank you so much.

**EDIT:** 
the connection string/configuration is OK, I am using the same context in many places in the same, as configured per app.config and/or web.config.

Comment: How are you configuring your DbContext's connection string ? Where is the configuration ?

Comment: @user957902 the same DBContext is used in other places, the configuration per web.config is OK.